# How can we prdecit inject object will be created from so many modules in my project?

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2

Suppose I have 3 modeules in OpenGraph. i.e for example

```
ObjectGraph og = new ObjectGraph.create(
        new moduleA();
        new moduleB();
        new moduleC();
 );
@module
public class moduleA{
   @Provides @Singleton Log providerLog(){
              return log;
     }
}
```

till now it seems to be okay. But I have a class named

```
publi class BaseActivity extends Activity {

@Inject
  Log log;
}
```

Here i am not specifiying any module in the @Injection. But Log object will be created in the class. I know this log object will be created from that moduleA module like injects{@moduleA}. How it will create Log module without specifying any module.

Anything wrong with my understanding or coding please suggest me. Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You **have** specified moduleA in the object graph. You will be injecting your BaseActivity class using the object graph, which is configured using moduleA.